# format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’

Tags: c

Each time I submit a program on hackerrank the following error occurs.

```
solution.c: In function ‘main’:
solution.c:22:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%d", &sum);
```

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me what this means?

Comment: Remove the & before `sum`, since you want to give printf the value, not the address of the value

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].

Comment: You are confusing `scanf` with `printf`...

Comment: post your code, otherwise we cannot point you to where the code is incorrect.  However, do you realize the difference between `int` and `int*`?  The `int` is what is expected, but your code has a pointer to a `int`.  in the line of code, the address of `sum` is being passed to `printf()`, However, when calling `printf()` only need to pass a pointer when you want to display an address.  So the line should be: `printf("%d", sum);`   <<-- notice, passing the content of `sum` rather than the address of sum

Answer (score 26):

I assume that you have declared `sum` as an `int`. So the correct call to `printf` is :

```
printf("%d", sum);
```

as `%d` specifier means that you are going to print an `int`, but you are passing the `int`'s address, which is a pointer to `int`, or `int *`.

---

***NOTE*** : Do not confuse `printf` with `scanf`, as the second *does require a pointer*. So, for reading variable `sum`, you would use :

```
scanf("%d", &sum);
```

but for printing, the correct way is without `&`, as written above.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to print the address of sum you can use `printf( "%p", &sum )`

Comment: You need to cast the address to `(void *)` before printing with `%p`: ["The argument shall be a pointer to void."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8)

Comment: @DavidBowling Like this: `printf("%p", (void *)&sum)`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Using the `%p` specifier is the right thing to do when printing an address, and you may get away with not doing the cast, but it is required according to the Standard.

Comment: I am not convinced this is true. The C11 standard 6.3.2.3 states that "[a] pointer to
any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
compare equal to the original pointer." 6.9.1.10 states (about function calls) that "the value of each argument expression is **converted to the type of the corresponding parameter as if by assignment**" (emphasis mine). It's correct that `scanf()` expects `void*`s, but the C standard explicitly states that any pointer type can be implicitly converted to void* during function call, making the explicit cast unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Int is a primitive, primitives are data stored in memory. each data chunck is set in a specific memory block, those blocks has "memory addresses" that refer to them.

If you define `int i = 1` your computer allocates an integer in memory (in a block, with a memory address f.e. 0xF00000) and sets its value to 1.
When you refer to this integer as `i`, you are accessing the value stored in 0xF00000, that happen to be `1`.

In C you can also get the `i` reference (the memory address it's allocated in) by prefixing it with & (ampersand), by doing this you will get the memory address of the variable rather than its value.

```
i === 1; // true
&i === 1; //false
&i === 0xF00000; //true
```

This memory address can be assigned to a pointer (a variable that 'points' to a memory address, thus, have no it's own value) so it can be accessed directly too [dereferencing it](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) so you can gather the value inside that memory block. This is achieved using `*`

```
int i = 1; //this allocates the 
int *ptr = &i; //defines a pointer that points to i address

/* now this works cause i is a primitive */
printf("%d", i);

/* this works also cause ptr is dereferenced, returning the
value from the address it points, in this case, i's value */
printf("%d", *ptr);
```

In your example, you are passing a reference to printf (printf asks for a value and is receiving a memory address) so it doesnt work.

Hope this helps you understand C and pointers better

Answer (score 0):

```js
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int var = 10;
    int* a = &var;
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

First i Used `"%d"` and it shows error that `format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’`
then I replace `"%d"` with `"%p"` and it Works.

```js
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int var = 10;
    int* a = &var;
    printf("%p", a);
    return 0;
}
```

you have to use `"%p"` to print address of a variable. Thank you